# How to find the max date for an individual Mutual Fund Sheme in DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Trying to solve a problem in DAX.

Have 4 tables in the model.

1. All_MF - This table contains the entries of the investment I have done in different schemes over a time period.
2. ALL_NAV - This table contains the entries of the NAV by date for the different schemes I have invested in. So there would be an entry for every day which has the NAV valeue.
3. MF_Details - This contains the list of the Schemes where I have invested in.
4. Date - The standard date table.

The model is as below:
[image: Data Model:]

Sample files attached:
All_MF
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/xwXUXhWv?theme=dark

All_NAV
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/0EcLuH32?theme=dark

MF_Details
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/HiecJepj?theme=dark

I am trying to add a calculated column in the ALL_MF table which would have the latest NAV_DATE for that scheme.

I tried using the below DAX but it populates with the MAX date irrespective of the scheme as I am unable to make a relationship between ALL_MF and ALL_NAV

```
LatestNAVDt = CALCULATE(MAXX(RELATEDTABLE(ALL_NAV),ALL_NAV[navDate]),ALL(ALL_NAV))
```

I wrote the below DAX measure to find the NAV value for the max date for the year selected and I am able to get the correct value, but then how do I calculate the current value of the investment as per the latest NAV

```
NAVValue =
    var MaxNavDt = MAXX(RELATEDTABLE(ALL_NAV),ALL_NAV[navDate])
    Return
        CALCULATE(MAXX(RELATEDTABLE(ALL_NAV),ALL_NAV[navValue]),
        FILTER(ALL_NAV,ALL_NAV[navDate] = MaxNavDt))
```

Please note that for Axis Midcap Fund - Direct Plan - Growth the NAV data is till 10/19 but for the other two it is till 10/20

Do let me know if I need to clarify as I have invested a lot of time to explain the scenario in detail.

Comment: It doesn't help your case that the latest NAV_DATE for all 3 schemes happens to be identical (20/10/2023). Suggest you manually amend one or more.

Comment: @JosWoolley I had made the changes but seems it did not get saved as I had mentioned the scenario in the thread specifically. Let me change and save it. Hope the changes reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LatestNAVDt =
  var scheme = 'ALL_MF'[Scheme_Name]
  var result = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), FILTER(ALL('ALL_NAV'), 'ALL_NAV'[SchemeName] = scheme))
  RETURN result
```

Or via REMOVEFILTERS:

```
LatestNAVDt = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), REMOVEFILTERS('Date'[Date]) )
```

Example: [image] Note that I deliberatly changed the data so that Midcap goes upto 10/18 only.

Comment: This would not work as it will give the same date as the date of the NAV_Dt of the ALL_MF table. Instead what I want is the Max navDt from the ALL_NAV table.

Comment: Updated answer to include ALL filter, and also provided a simpler option with REMOVEFILTERS

Comment: It worked okay on my sample (see above). Go for option 1 then with the Filter(ALL(..))

Comment: The REMOVEFILTER solution does not work but yes the ALL filter solution works.

Comment: Can someone please help me understand. Why do I need to add the filter as the ROW Context is already present. I was anticipating that I will have to go the RELATEDTABLE route. How are we able to access the All_NAV table from the All_MF table !!!

Comment: You need to add the filter with the ALL as you want to return the full table without any relationships interfering (like from the Date table). Without the filter you will only get the rows that are related by the two dimension tables. You can access/query any table from any table. You can filter any other table without the need of a relationship.