# Data for previous non blank date in DAX

Tags: dax

This is a follow up of a previous post of mine. The link to the previous post is:

[How to find the max date for an individual Mutual Fund Sheme in DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349952/how-to-find-the-max-date-for-an-individual-mutual-fund-sheme-in-dax/77350101?noredirect=1#comment136366125_77350101)

The current issue that I am facing is that I am unable to calculate the investment value  of the previous date.

To calculate the value of the previous date investment I believe I will have to do the below:

1. Find the NAV of the previous date from the ALL_NAV table for all of the Mutual Fund Scheme.

And I am trying to do this with the below DAX but getting error.

```
PrevNAV = 
VAR schemename = DISTINCT(ALL_MF[Scheme_Name])
var dt = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]) -1,FILTER(ALL_NAV,ALL_NAV[SchemeName] = schemename && not ISBLANK(ALL_NAV[navValue])))
var nav = CALCULATE(SUM(ALL_NAV[navValue]),FILTER(ALL(ALL_NAV), ALL_NAV[navDate] = dt ))
return nav
```

2. Once I get the NAV of the previous date for each Mutual Fund scheme then I will have to multiply the NAV value with the corresponding investment amount in the ALL_MF table.

Getting really confused as to how to achieve the above.

Some help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I would like to highlight that the DAX is not throwing any error but then when I am trying to visualize the data using Matrix visualization for the NAV values by Scheme I do not see any data. The visualization message says can't display data. I have already invested close to 6 hours trying to solve it but to no success so looking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Calculated Column
PrevDayNAV = 
  var rScheme = 'ALL_MF'[Scheme_Name] // this row's scheme
  var schemeFilter = FILTER(ALL('ALL_NAV'), ALL_NAV[SchemeName] = rScheme && NOT ISBLANK('ALL_NAV'[navValue]))
  var latestDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), schemeFilter)
  var prevAvailableDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), schemeFilter, 'ALL_NAV'[navDate] < latestDate)

  var NAV = CALCULATE(SUM(ALL_NAV[navValue]), schemeFilter, 'ALL_NAV'[navDate] = prevAvailableDate)
  RETURN NAV

// Measure
* PrevDayNAV = 
  var rScheme = VALUES('ALL_MF'[Scheme_Name])
  var schemeFilter = FILTER(ALL('ALL_NAV'), ALL_NAV[SchemeName] in rScheme && NOT ISBLANK('ALL_NAV'[navValue]))
  var latestDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), schemeFilter)
  var prevAvailableDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]), schemeFilter, 'ALL_NAV'[navDate] < latestDate)

  var NAV = CALCULATE(SUM(ALL_NAV[navValue]), schemeFilter, 'ALL_NAV'[navDate] = prevAvailableDate)
  RETURN NAV
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out on this. I do not get any results for PrevNAV when I run it on Monday as there is no data for Saturday and Sunday but instead there is data for Friday.

Comment: I've updated the answer above. Apologies, I earlier thought this calculated column was to be in `ALL_MF`. Regarding your issue on Monday, you can't do {date} - 1 as this will give you Sunday which doesn't exist in the data. Above answer gets `latestDate` then finds `prevAvailableDate`.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for late response as I was sick. What value does var schemeFilter contain. I could understand the other code but not what is held in this variable. If I am correct is a Table.

Comment: `schemeFilter` is just a `FILTER` variable to help with code re-use.

Comment: DAX sure is tough. Struggling to get hold of it. Thanks for helping me out Sam Nseir. The above is calculated column. But what if I wanted it to be a measure and also wanted the days to go in past be dynamic like 5 days, 31 days, 1 year etc.

Comment: Updated answer above with the measure version. Past days dynamic, I think you can update `var preAvailableDate` line with `'ALL_NAV'[navDate] < latestDate - {XDAYS}`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the below but it also does not return the result when the latest day is Monday.

`PrevDayNAV =  var scheme = 'ALL_MF'[Scheme_Name] var PrevDt = CALCULATE(DATEADD(LASTDATE('ALL_NAV'[navDate]),-1,DAY), FILTER(ALL('ALL_NAV'), 'ALL_NAV'[SchemeName] = scheme && NOT ISBLANK(ALL_NAV[navValue]))) var NAV = CALCULATE(SUM(ALL_NAV[navValue]),FILTER(ALL(ALL_NAV), ALL_NAV[navDate] = PrevDt && 'ALL_NAV'[SchemeName] = scheme)) RETURN NAV`